# Android sqllite, querying an object that is a property of another object

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How do I query an object that has another object as a property? I need to get the values of the property as well. Here's my model:

```
public class Department {
 public int DeptId;
 public string DeptName;
}

public class Employee {
 public int Id;
 public string Name;
 public int DeptId;
 public Department Department;
}
```

I'm coming from a c# background, and I could do this with c# using Entity Framework. Now it seems like this model works but when I included a sqllite functionality for the objects I'm not sure how to query it.

Here's my first try, but I'm not sure if this is the best way

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployeesWithDepartments(){
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN Department d on e.DeptId = d.Id" , null);

    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Employee emp = new Employee(); 
            emp.Id = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            emp.Name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Name"));

            Department dep = new Department();
            dep.Id = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            dep.Name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Name"));

            emp.Department = dep;
            employees.add(emp);
        }while (res.moveToNext());
     }
     return employees;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confused.  SQLite doesn't have objects.  Its a table based database (like almost all databases).  You can map objects into tables, but you have to create those mappings yourself.  Since SQLite doesn't have objects, it definitely doesn't have subobjects.  You generally make something like it by joining another table with a foreign key constraint on the main table, but it really is defined by your schema.  There is no generic answer for you.